# How to scroll the div by the scroll bar only of same div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I just want to scroll the div ( overflow scroll ) by only the bar in right hand side not on mouse roll, touch.

```css
body
{
    height:1000px
}
.news_list {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<body><div class="news_list">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prevent **[`mousewheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel)** event default action using **[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** or by returning false `return false;`

```js
$('.news_list').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px
}
.news_list {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="news_list">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
    sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, It work on desktop but did not work on mobile browser.
any help?

Comment: I know mousewheel for desktop, but we have touch for mobile so i dont want to scroll touching on dive portion. but scroll on side scroll bar of the same div.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oLhdsp5z/)

```
$(".news_list").bind("mousewheel", function () {
    return false;
});
```

Cancel the mousewheel on the div with class `news_list`

Comment: Thank you for the solution, It work on desktop but did not work on mobile browser. any help?

Comment: is there a mouse when using mobile?what kind of mobile has mouse on it?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstand. we have touch feature for scrolling right?
so i want to prevent the scroll by touch in the div portion, 

as the scroll should be done by the side scroll bar of same div.

$(".news_list").bind("touchmove", function () {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
});
this code will bind all the touch for the div.